# Separating jQuery Functions?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm just trying to have 3 links, and when you click on one it renders a corresponding form.  I thought I was familiar with jQuery, but apparently not as weird things are happening.  My code is as follows

jQuery

```
$("#show_basic_selector").click(function() {
    hide().after('<%= j render("basic") %>');
});

$("#show_team_selector").click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});

$("#show_custom_selector").click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

View

```
<%= link_to "Show form 1", { :action => 'new_order' }, id: "show_basic_selector", remote: true %>

<%= link_to "Show form 2", { :action => 'new_order' }, id: "show_team_selector", remote: true %>

<%= link_to "Show form 3", { :action => 'new_order' }, id: "show_custom_selector", remote: true %>
```

My problem is when I use the alert function to test to see if it works, when I click on a link it will start to display a random number of alerts (2-15) when I click on it, and when I set up the render function, it hides all three and displays all three forms.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What do you hide() method ?

Comment: How are you binding the handlers? Are they perhaps being run multiple times?

Comment: Normally I'll have all three with a hide().after... or alert... but I did it mixed to show the two I'm having problems with

Comment: What does `hide()` return?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, .hide() will make the link (the words) "Show Form 1" disappear

Answer (score 0):

You probably are attaching multiple event handlers and I think you mean to target $(this) in your first function. try unattaching other event handlers to make sure you only get the one. This is not ideal because there is likely a design flaw or bug somewhere in your app, but try this:

```
$("#show_basic_selector").off().on('click' , function() {
    $(this).hide().after('<%= j render("basic") %>');
});

$("#show_team_selector").off().on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello");
});

$("#show_custom_selector").off().on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: so this aleast stops it from doing something repeatedly, but it only allows me to click them sequestially (that is, I cannot click the second or third unless I've already clicked the first).  
And perhaps I'm confused on what you mean by attaching the event handlers, but all the code that is associated is listed in the post.  It's two files, those 17 files is all the code